# SharePoint memory settings

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, 2016, sql-server, settings

I am gonna build a new SharePoint 2016 farm,

- 2 web and app servers
- 2 DB servers cluster

What's the setting required for SQL memory in management studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Management Studio, there are two options for the Allocated **`Server Memory`**,

- **`The Minimum Server memory in MB`**. (`Default value is 0`).

  - The recommended settings should be the default.
- **`The maximum Server memory in MB`**. (`Default value is 2147483647 about 2 TB`)

  - The recommended settings should be less than the amount of installed RAM.

**Ex:** if the installed RAM is 32 GB, so try to set it to

```
32- [(the allocated memory for OP) + other allocated memory for other systems]
```

**`Other systems like`**

- Operating System.
- Antivirus.
- Other SQL Instances.

---

**For further details, check**

- An equation that may help you to calculate and [set the Max Server memory limit](http://mstechtalk.com/set-memory-limits-sql-server/).
- [Best practices for SQL Server in a SharePoint Server farm](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/best-practices-for-sql-server-in-a-sharepoint-server-farm)

Comment: Glad to hear it helped you,